# Android repeating alarm minimum interval?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I set my repeating alarm to trigger every 2 minutes but instead it triggers exactly every 5 minutes. I have tested different intervals under 5 minutes but this behavior does not change. Is there a minimum Android enforces? I am using 4.1.2. Here is my code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateAlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 120000, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: The first alarm will be triggered after 5 minutes also?

Comment: No the first alarm triggers immediately as expected.

Comment: Then the problem maybe what you do when receive an alarm,please show use these code.

Comment: I tried on emulator 4.1.2 and it fires the alarm at the proper interval. The problem exist only when run on my phone where it will only do every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed that problem adding a WakeLock:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLoc wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelock");
wakeLock.acquire(180000); //Auto-close in three minutes
```

You should also add permissions to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put the wakelock?

Comment: Everytime the action is trigerred by AlarmManager